# Subcomplexes of the infinitely-dimensional sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying to understand better what Hatcher does in the beginning chapter on cell complexes and so in this sense I would really like someone to elucidate for me what are the subcomplexes of $S^{\infty}$, with the cell structure described in the book, having two cells in each dimension.

The clearer the explanation the better! Thanks

Comment: Have you tried making the list of subcomplexes yourself? For example. What are the 1-dimensional subcomplexes?

Comment: of course i tried; I'm pretty sure the subcomplexes are the $n$-dimensional spheres and the $n$-dimensional spheres, each along with an $n+1$ cell attached to the previous sphere along its boundary. but i was hoping for a detailed answer...

Comment: Why don't you write what you did in the question?

Comment: @TJIF - do you understand how to make, for example, $S^2$ with two cells in each dimension (less than 3).

Comment: got it, thanks.